# Why does SQL Server allow this JOIN syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, syntax

I just generated some SQL from within Cognos Report Studio. I've sanitized the tables and fields but left the structure in place. Below is the Native SQL that was generated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.FIELD1
FROM TABLE1 
TABLE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
TABLE2 ON TABLE1.KEY1 = TABLE2.KEY1
WHERE TABLE2.FLAG1 = 0 
AND TABLE1.FLAG2 = 0 
AND TABLE1.FLAG3 = 0 
AND TABLE2.FLAG4 = 0
AND TABLE2.FLAG5 = 0
```

To my surprise the above syntax actually runs in SQL Server. I was expecting a syntax error.

I normally code these up like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.FIELD1
FROM TABLE1 
/*TABLE1*/ LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
/*TABLE2*/ ON TABLE1.KEY1 = TABLE2.KEY1
WHERE TABLE2.FLAG1 = 0 
AND TABLE1.FLAG2 = 0 
AND TABLE1.FLAG3 = 0 
AND TABLE2.FLAG4 = 0
AND TABLE2.FLAG5 = 0
```

The above syntax also runs but I expected it to.

So, I'm curious as to why SQL Server allows both of these query syntax. The top query appears to have redundant references to TABLE1 and TABLE2.

Why does the query1 work?

Is there a name for the syntax used in query1?

Comment: You mean table alias name? `FROM TABLE1 
TABLE1` is same as `FROM TABLE1  AS TABLE1` but alias has the same name as original table

Comment: What's the problem?, it's just giving aliases to the tables

Comment: [Using Table Aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @lad2025 Doh makes perfect sense now. It through me for two reasons : 1. The alias table name is the same name as the table name. 2. The alias table name appeared on the line below and not adjacent to the table. Thx.

Comment: SQL treats line breaks as spaces and ignores extra spaces in the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general form of a join would look as follows (with [] indicating optional parts, as usual):

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM   table1 [table1 alias]
[LEFT] [OUTER] JOIN table2 [table2 alias]
[WHERE ...]
```

So in your first snippet, you have the table `table1` with the alias `table1` being joined on `table2` with the alias `table2`. These aliases are pointless, but not illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Your query would be easier to write and read if you used simpler table aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.FIELD1
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T1.KEY1 = T2.KEY1
WHERE T2.FLAG1 = 0 AND
      T1.FLAG2 = 0 AND
      T1.FLAG3 = 0 AND
      T2.FLAG4 = 0 AND
      T2.FLAG5 = 0;
```

In other words, you can use any string for the table alias, even the tablename.  Redundant, but allowed by SQL Server and basically all other databases.